# Why my replace method does not work with the string [B]?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following dataset called world_top_ten:

`

```
    Most populous countries 2000    2015    2030[A]
0   China[B]    1270    1376    1416
1   India   1053    1311    1528
2   United States   283 322 356
3   Indonesia   212 258 295
4   Pakistan    136 208 245
5   Brazil  176 206 228
6   Nigeria 123 182 263
7   Bangladesh  131 161 186
8   Russia  146 146 149
9   Mexico  103 127 148
10  World total 6127    7349    8501
```

`

I am trying to replace the [B] with "":

```
world_top_ten['Most populous countries'].str.replace(r'"[B]"', '')
```

And it is returning me:

```
0          China[B]
1             India
2     United States
3         Indonesia
4          Pakistan
5            Brazil
6           Nigeria
7        Bangladesh
8            Russia
9            Mexico
10      World total
Name: Most populous countries, dtype: object
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Because `[]` is special regex character escape it:

```
world_top_ten['Most populous countries'].str.replace(r'\[B\]', '', regex=True)
```